# scala: Using method of class with type parameter that doesn't require the type

Tags: scala

In this class, the method `incrementX` is independent of the type parameter `A`.

```
class Item[A](var x: Int, var y: A) {
    def incrementX() = {
        this.x += 1
    }
    def changeY(func: A => A) = {
        this.y = func(y)
    }
}
```

How can I invoke it given an instance with an unknown type parameter, without extracting one of the methods to another class or trait?

```
def incrementXTwice(item: --type that incrementX can be invoked on--) {
    item.incrementX()
    item.incrementX()
}
```

(The examples are for illustration)

Comment: `def incrementXTwice(item: Item[_]): Unit = {`

Answer (score 2):

Existential type:

```
def incrementXTwice(item: Item[_])
```

or type parameter

```
def incrementXTwice[A](item: Item[A])
```

The former assumes that knowledge of specific `A` is lost and cannot be recovered, the later assumes that method don't need to know it but caller does.